# How to know the last time a script was run?

Tags: unix

The command *ls -lu script_name.sh* only gives last access time of script.
Is there any way to determine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processes in Linux do not normally leave traces after they terminate, unless they create or modify files, write syslog messages, or [audit subsystem is on and it keeps track of `exec*` calls](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/chap-system_auditing.html).